# How to get unknown number of parameters using php

Tags: php, foreach, get

I am trying to get parameters in php using get.
The page I'm getting the parameters from is with ajax meaning I don't know how many time the parameters was sent but I know the type of them.
Example of what I can get:

> makeOrder.php?size=37&quantity=2
>   makeOrder.php?size=37&quantity=2&size=39&quantity=5
>   makeOrder.php?size=37&quantity=2&size=39&quantity=5&size=36&quantity=10

and so on...

I wrote only to get one parameter

```
<?php
    //create a mySQL DB connection:
    $dbhost = "166.62.8.11";
    $dbuser = "auxstudDB5";
    $dbpass = "auxstud5DB1!";
    $dbname = "auxstudDB5";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    //testing connection success
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("DB connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }

    $size1 = $_GET['size'];
    $quantity1= $_GET['quantity'];

    $connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"); 

    foreach(size as $size1){
        foreach (quantity as $quantity1) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_202 VALUES('$size1','$quantity1')";
            $result = $connection->query($sql);
            if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "ok ";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
            }               

        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);  
?>
```

I understood I can use maybe foreach but didn't really understand how to go over size and quantity

Comment: Send them as an array size[]=37&quantity[]=2&size[]=39&quantity[]=5

Comment: I believe that's not possible. With `var_dump($_GET)` you'll always get the last pair of size and quantity value.

Comment: And I assume this is not yur *production DATABASE credentails*

Comment: foreach(size as $size1){ what is it? As per this line u need to use param as an array..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you two different way:

#### 1. GET variables as array

In your javascript/jQuery script, you have to call php url in a way like:

```
makeOrder.php?size[]=50&quantity[]=10&size[]=10&quantity[]=2
```

and then, in php file, your `$_GET` variable will assume this value:

```
Array
(
    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 10
        )
    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

#### 2. GET variable as JSON

In your javascript/jQuery script, you have to call php url in a way like:

```
makeOrder.php?data=[{"size":"50","quantity":"10"},{"size":"10","quantity":"2"}]
```

To obtain the JSON string, you can use js function [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

and then, in php file, retrieving the values in this way:

```
$data = json_decode( $_GET['data'] );
```

will result an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [size] => 50
            [quantity] => 10
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [size] => 10
            [quantity] => 2
        )
)
```

To obtain an array of arrays (instead of objects) you can use `json_decode( $_GET['data'], True )` instead of `json_decode( $_GET['data'] )`